# How can I access my Store from a service?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I use NgRx recently with effects to manage send API requests.
My API requests are in a service and my effect uses this service. Very classic.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MaterialService {
  private url = "materials";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMaterials () {
    return this.http.get (this.url).pipe (
      catchError (this.handleError)
    );
  }

  handleError (error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<never> {
    return throwError (error.message);
  }
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class MaterialEffects {

  @Effect() loadMaterial$ = this.dataPersistence.fetch(
    MaterialActionTypes.LoadMaterial,
    {
      run: (action: LoadMaterial, state: MaterialPartialState) => {

        return this.materialService.getMaterials ().pipe (
          map (data => {
            return new MaterialLoaded(data);
          }),
//          catchError (error => of (new MaterialLoadError (error)))
        );
      },

      onError: (action: LoadMaterial, error) => {
        console.error('Error', error);
        return new MaterialLoadError(error);
      }
    }
  );
...
```

Overall it works great. I just love it :)

But for certain requests, I need to recover some ID to create my URL. These IDs are mostly generic IDs. For example the ID of our client.
`https://my.example.com/perimeters/[PERIMETER_ID]/relationships/users`

How can I use my service to retrieve my content ID from my store, create my URL and return my Observable as expected?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the store into your effects class `MaterialEffects`, and get the value you need, then pass that as a parameter into your `MaterialService`.

So your effect would look like:

```
@Injectable()
export class MaterialEffects {

    constructor(private store: Store<any>)

    @Effect() loadMaterial$ = this.dataPersistence.fetch(
        MaterialActionTypes.LoadMaterial,
        {
            run: (action: LoadMaterial, state: MaterialPartialState) => {

                return this.store.pipe(
                    select(x => x.perimiterId),
                    mergeMap((perimiterId) => {
                        materialService.getMaterials(perimiterId).pipe(
                            map(data => {
                                return new MaterialLoaded(data);
                            }),
                            // catchError (error => of (new MaterialLoadError (error)))
                        )
                    })
                )
            },

            onError: (action: LoadMaterial, error) => {
                console.error('Error', error);
                return new MaterialLoadError(error);
            }
        }
    );
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So `perimeterId` will be an observable that I will transmit to my service. But my service can not use an observable to do an operation on a string of characters. No ?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. I need to get better acquainted with RxJs operators and what are typical uses.